# Objective-C - how to put reference ID while using NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, nsmutablearray

Is there anyway on `[randomSelection addObject:renderView];` assign custom peerID references (such as id: cgiLoC0OdMNtVph3aMZV or cxeeeLoC0OdMNtVph3aMZV), for later to query from some random/unsorted UIView's?

For example: while create i have such as below:

```
//@property (copy, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *randomSelection;
//UIView *renderView;
//renderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(padding_x, padding_y, 50, 50)];
NSMutableArray *randomSelection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[randomSelection addObject:renderView];
//self.randomSelection = randomSelection;
```

But there are some situation when i need to remove some of the UIView but in that case i only have some peerID references. How do i have some custom reference while using `NSMutableArray`

```
- (void)callingRemoveMethod:(NSString *)peerID {
  NSLog(@"removed %@", peerID);

  /* instead of objectAtIndex is there a way to query 
   it by any custom references? */

  //UIView *test = [self.randomSelection objectAtIndex:0];
  //test.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could use an `NSMutableDictionary` instead and use your `ID` as the key to the dictionary.
2. `UIView` has a tag property (an `int`) that you can use for this purpose, but it can't be arbitrary information (just an `int`)

**EDIT:**

```
NSMutableDictionary *jobs = [NSMutableDictionary
                             dictionaryWithDictionary:@{
                                 @"Audi TT" : @"John",
                                 @"Audi Quattro (Black)" : @"Mary",
                                 @"Audi Quattro (Silver)" : @"Bill",
                                 @"Audi A7" : @"Bill"
                             }];
// Transfer an existing job to Mary
[jobs setObject:@"Mary" forKey:@"Audi TT"];
// Finish a job
[jobs removeObjectForKey:@"Audi A7"];
// Add a new job
jobs[@"Audi R8 GT"] = @"Jack";
```

Comment: Thank you `NSMutableDictionary` would be great, i will try this one now. unfortunately my UIView references are arbitrary